# Is there a way to change vs code settings based on current open directory?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if there is a way to change my theme based on folder name in Visual Studio Code. I'm constantly mix up together my front-end and back-end projects. Thanks for replies :D

Answer (score 1):

Inside the folder add folder `.vscode` and add `settings.json` inside that folder with the following code:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Kimbie Dark"
}
```